# How can I interrupt asynctask in my main activity from a class to display alertDialog?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Here is the code snippet from my class, how i'm calling alertDialog. In my case if count is zero the asynctask must terminate and display dialog:

```
if(count == 0){

            NumberPlateActivity np  = new NumberPlateActivity();

            np.dialog(con);
}
```

And here is the method, in my main activity, which suppose to interrupt the asynctask and bring up the dialog:

```
public void dialog(final Context context){

    new Thread() { public void run() {    
NumberPlateActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            ImageProc stop = new ImageProc();// ImageProc - asynctask
            stop.cancel(true);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
            builder.setMessage("Plate not found. Try again!")
                   .setCancelable(false)
                       .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setClass(context.getApplicationContext(), ANPR.class);
                            context.startActivity(intent);

                       }
                   });

        } 
    }});
    }
}.start();
}
```

After running the code I get this error: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called `Looper.prepare()`.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a handler inside the main thread that runs the activity. You should do it in a separate thread.

I do not see any handler in your code so you are probably using it somewhere we do not see here.

Answer (score 0):

If you're terminating your AsyncTask, why not just do:

```
void onPostExecute(...)
{
    if (count == 0)
    {
        NumberPlateActivity np = new NumberPlateActivity();
        np.dialog(con);
    }
}
```

Seems the easiest solution to me! It also means you can get rid of the `Thread` and `Runnable` in `public void dialog(final Context context)`.

As for your `public void dialog(final Context context)` method, I cannot see any reason for having the `Thread` class, and:

```
ImageProc stop = new ImageProc();// ImageProc - asynctask
stop.cancel(true);
```

I cannot see any obvious reason to create an `AsyncTask` and then immediately delete it.